# Getting result of FOR XML into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
   SELECT @Name = Name FROM Table FOR XML AUTO
```

Does not work, how do you get the XML result from using `FOR XML` into a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT @Name = CONVERT(XML, (
  SELECT Name
  FROM SomeTable
  FOR XML AUTO
));
```

You can try it without the wrapping `CONVERT(XML, (...))` statement but I've found that SQL Server doesn't like assigning to XML variables without that explicit cast.